# To use $NODE_ENV with if condition in windows cmd

Tags: nodemon, npm-scripts

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "if [[ $NODE_ENV == 'production' ]]; then node ./bin/www; else nodemon ./bin/www; fi"
},
```

The above code is used in Unix terminal and I want to use the same in windows `cmd`.

But when I try to do that I get `NODE_ENV` was unexpected at this time.

I want a proper code which can be executed in windows `cmd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following cross-platform solution that works successfully regardless of whether the shell is `cmd` *(windows)* or `sh` *(*nix)*. It essentially utilizes node.js to replicate the same conditional logic and to shell out the appropriate command.

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node -e \"const cmd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'node' : 'nodemon'; require('child_process').execSync(cmd + ' ./bin/www', { stdio: [0,1,2] });\""
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `start` npm script does the following:

1. Utilizes the node.js command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) to evaluate the inline JavaScript.
2. Using the [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), i.e. the part that reads:

   ```js
   const cmd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'node' : 'nodemon'
   ```

   - We utilize the [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) property to check the value of the `NODE_ENV` environment variable.
   - If the value of the `NODE_ENV` environment variable equals `production`  we assign the `node` command to the `cmd` variable. Otherwise we assign the `nodemon` command.
3. In the part that reads:

   ```js
   require('child_process').execSync(cmd + ' ./bin/www', { stdio: [0,1,2] });
   ```

   - We [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) the builtin [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) method from the `child_process` module.
   - Then we execute either the `node ./bin/www` or the `nodemon ./bin/www` command based on what was obtained at point 2 (above).
   - The [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio) part configures the pipes for stdin, stdout, stderr in the child process.